# Unable to initialise a matrix

Tags: r

I wanted to create a matrix in R so I typed this:

```
a<- matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
print(a)
```

But instead of it executing it gives the error:

*Error in matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE) :
unused arguments (c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)*

At first i thought I had gotten the syntax wrong but i pasted many examples from different sites but same issue.

Comment: So what is the issue with rstudio? I need it to work for college assignments.

Comment: My apologies i am new to stack so I have missed the line change.they are in seperate line in the code.still it shows error

Comment: Make sure it is reproducible. I can reproduce yours error even with a line seperation.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: It means it can run well in my machine.  Can you run  `matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)`?

Comment: I can run the same statement on gbd online compiler with no problem.it seems to be a rstudio thing but I cant figure out what

Comment: Are you willing to clear all your variables in RStudio with `rm(list = ls())`then retry `matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)`?

Comment: It worked thank you

Comment: I guess you must use  some bad variable names  which overrides the default.

Comment: What can be classified as bad variable name?i do tend to reuse the variables as I do all the questions on the same file.

Comment: e.g. `matrix <- ...` , `matrix` is a default R function, but here you use it as a variable name. Anyway, be careful , good luck.

Comment: `matrix <- function(x) lenght(x);
 matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)`
Error in matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE). One possible way to  recover the error.

Comment: Try `base::matrix(base::c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)`. That should work, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same output as Peace. The main problem is the number of entries in the matrix. There are 5 entries for 2 rows. As mentioned in the warning 5 is not a multiple of 2. So R uses the first entry, which is 1 in our case, again as the second-row third-column entry of the matrix.

```r
a<- matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#> Warning in matrix(c(1:5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE): data length [5] is not a sub-
#> multiple or multiple of the number of rows [2]
print(a)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]    4    5    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

When you change the entries of the matrix as below, there is no problem:

```r
a<- matrix(c(1:6), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
print(a)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]    4    5    6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thankyou coskun but that's wasn't the problem I had as Peace suggested I had something to do with bad variables in the environment.I cleared it out and everything was fine after that.I did however correct the vector of 1 to 5 to 1 to 6